# Script needed to create directory listing from html breadcrumb file

Tags: python, html

I've got a "html" text file that has a file tree directory listed in bullet format. I need to recombine this into a normal directory string.

What I have:
[Snippet of HTML Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow0Tj.png)

---

How it displays:
[How the HTML Docuement Displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKpqg.png)

What I need it to look like:

- C:\computer list.csv
- D:\DeptShare\Accounting.DS_Store
- D:\DeptShare\Accounting\New Folder\8-1-18.xls
- D:\DeptShare\Accounting\Physical Inventory\Copy of PhysInv Data Entry Dump 2016.xlsx
- D:\DeptShare\Accounting\Physical Inventory\ PhysInv Data Entry Dump 2016.xlsx